# Tennis grand slam trophies

Tags: tennis, awards, grand-slam, wimbledon

How many different trophies were there at each grand slam? And where can I find some photos of them? For example Wimbledon trophy nowadays looks differently as the one Rod Laver once won. Roland Garros current trophy is given to a winner only from year 1981.